# Get data from my json file to show in my blade.php

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-blade

Good day all

I have a project that has some basic data stored inside a JSON file. I also have a function in my traits folder that can read the data and put it in an array. My problem is I don't know how to get this array from the traits through the controller and route and then use it to show data in my blade.php views.

NOTE: The route works and the functions in traits are available already.

Controller:

```
public function index()
  {
      $jsonArray=$this->read_data('genre.json');
      return view('genre.index')->with('genresArray', $jsonArray );
  }
```

Trait:

```
  public static function read_data($json_file): mixed
 {

    $file_data = array();
    $file_data=json_decode(file_get_contents(base_path('storage/data/'.$json_file)),true);
    return $file_data;
}
```

View:

```
<?php echo $genresArray['genre']?>
```

jSonFile:

```
jSon File:
[{"genre":"Action","recordId":"8889d8017ba519b48710c1fa6cbe40b6"}, 
    {"genre":"Romance","recordId":"8ed28b04ef0ccc3ea2caa6265c3b36ec"},
    {"genre":"Sci-Fi","recordId":"85ed64f9b41d1984d4272ed6041af204"},
    {"genre":"Thriller","recordId":"c0d50ced298b85a1b92748dc7f05ac47"},
    {"genre":"Comedy","recordId":"3608cdef8df2b671defa5c1a5bad3f63"},
    {"genre":"Family","recordId":"cc52b3c8bc56921a15592b7682b07c52"}
  ]
```

ERROR:Undefined array key "genre"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, Import the trait to your Controller Class for example . Assuming (FileReadProcessor is the name of your trait)

```
use App\Utils\Traits\FileReadProcessor;

class FileReaderControllerr extends Controller{
//this is important 
use FileReadProcessor;

private function index(Request $request){

  return View::make('viewPage')->with('genresArray', self::read_data());

}

}
```

On the view,  you can then access it with  foreach based on the content of your file.

```
For instance 
@foreach ($file_array as $item)
    {{$item['genre']}}
    {{$item['recordId']}}
@endforeach
```

You can echo file_array[0]['genre'] (because an array was returned) if you are sure there are element in the return value and you don't want to iterate

```
<?php echo $genresArray[0]['genre']?>
```

Please note : the mixed instance in your trait will only work on php 8.0.0 >

Comment: I did edit the post with the code

Comment: I still get the same error, When I dump the array with varDump the data shows fine from the array but when trying to get a single entry in the array I get an error. Can someone please help

Comment: Because your trait method is a static method, you will have to call the method using self:: (Do not forget to import the trait in your class) i.e $jsonArray=self::read_data('genre.json'); 

Also , you are returning an array to the view so you have to consider the index of the array. i.e $genresArray[0]['genre']  or you will have to iterate through the array.

I have edited my origin post

Comment: This solved my problem thank you so much for your help. Now I must just find a way to hide the ID from the user.

Comment: You are welcome. I am glad I was able to help